# How would I reduce the height of my gradient background starting from the top?

Tags: html, css, debugging, gradient, linear-gradients

How would I reduce the height of my gradient background shade from the top rather than the bottom while keeping my gradient background shade in place?

For example, if you reduce the `height` to, say, `50%` - the height gets reduced starting from the bottom rather than the top.

I've tried using negative values for `height` but that didn't seem to do it.  I've also made other attempts to fix this but to no avail :(.

What's a good way to solve this issue?

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yp1c7m38/2/) for reference

HTML:

```
<div class="rectangle-left"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectangle-left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 129px;
    background: linear-gradient( 270deg, rgba(0, 31, 168, 0.9) 32.81%, rgba(0, 31, 168, 0) 100%);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: bottom:0 to your element ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif perfect!! thanks!